# Creating an etch-a-sketch with jQuery, draw function will not work with other divs in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I mouse over the divs I've created only the top left corner div will be affected with the addClass() method. All other divs remain unaltered when I mouse over them. Why is that? Here is the html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/etch.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 760px;
}

#grid {
    width: 250px;
    height: 185px;
    float: left;
}

.draw {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Here is my .js file:

```
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    while(count < 16){
        $('#wrapper').append('<div id="grid">*</div>');
        count++
    }

    $("#grid").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('draw');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).addClass('draw');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs need to be unique, you are creating all the divs with the same ID.

Try changing your append to this

```
 $('#wrapper').append('<div id="grid-"'+ count +'" class="grid">*</div>');
```

Then in you CSS and other JS target the grid elements with the class selector `.grid`